# How to get a list of users who have setup 365 MFA and those who haven't

Tags: powershell, office365, intune

Title pretty much says it all.

Ideally in a PS Script.

We've had a look around and can't seem to find anything that actually works, also not everyone uses the app so we can't rely on those numbers.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Did you find the solution? You can use below PowerShell cmdlet to get list of users with their MFA status.

> Get-MsolUser -All | foreach{
>   $DisplayName=$*.DisplayName
>
>   $MFAStatus=$*.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State
>   if($MFAStatus-eq $null) {  MFAStatus="Disabled" }
>   Write-host $DisplayName $MFAStatus }

or you can download pre-built script to [Export O365 users MFA status](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Export-Office-365-Users-81747c73) with attributes like MFA Status, Activation Status, Default MFA Method, All MFA Methods, MFA Phone, MFA Email, License Status, IsAdmin, SignIn Status.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you look?
There are pre-built scripts on the S PowerShellgallery.com for this use case.

[Script List all Office 365 MFA Enabled Users](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-Office-365-MFA-ae97c474)

[List all Office 365 MFA Enabled Users](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-all-Office-365-MFA-ae97c474/view/Discussions)

> The following script lists all Office 365 MFA Enabled Users together
>   with their common properties, such as: DisplayName UserPrincipalName
>   IsLicensed MFAState RememberDevicesNotIssuedBefore
>   StrongAuthenticationUserDetailsPhoneNumber
>   StrongAuthenticationUserDetailsEmail
>
> Download : Get-MsolMFAStatus-v1.2.ps1

As well as many other resource / samples / discussions on the web on how to do this.

[Powershell CMDlets for MFA Settings?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory/Powershell-CMDlets-for-MFA-Settings/m-p/157759#M1324)

```
Connect-MsolService
$User = Get-MSolUser -UserPrincipalName user@domain.com
$User.StrongAuthenticationMethod
```

[List Office 365 Users that have MFA "Disabled"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/715dc1cd-1013-4bdd-a587-0e35f1ad1dbb/list-office-365-users-that-have-mfa-quotdisabledquot)

```
Get-MsolUser -all | 
    select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,@{N="MFA Status"; E={ 
        if($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -ne 0){ 
            $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements[0].State
        } else { 
            'Disabled'}
        }
    }
```

Just list all you users, then run the script to get enabled users and compare.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use below script to get MFA user details.
https://techcognizance.com/2020/12/24/get-microsoft-365-mfa-users-details/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.